# Minimum value of: $x^7(yz-1)+y^7(zx-1)+z^7(xy-1)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math

> $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive reals such that $x+y+z=xyz$. Find the minimum value of:
>   $$x^7(yz-1)+y^7(zx-1)+z^7(xy-1)$$

I put it in the form $x^6y +x^6z+y^6x+y^6z+z^6x +z^6y$. I tried AM-GM but it's not helping.

Answer (score 5):

$$x^6y +x^6z+y^6x+y^6z+z^6x +z^6y \ge 6 (xyz)^{7/3}$$

Also $xyz = x+y+z \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{xyz} \implies xyz \ge 3\sqrt3$.

Comment: $7x^2y^2z^2$? I think it should be $6(xyz)^{7/3}$.

Comment: Don't you mean $xyz \ge 3\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @achillehui Right.  Shouldn't type on phone I guess!  Will correct.

Comment: @achillehui Many thanks.  Was struggling with the phone keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

Step:$1$ $$x^6y +x^6z+y^6x+y^6z+z^6x +z^6y \geq 6x^2y^2z^2(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
Step:$2$$$\frac{\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}}{3} \geq \frac{1}{(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$
$$(xyz)^{\frac{2}{3}} \geq 3$$ 
Next step : Substitute result of step:$2$ in step:$1$